# Ruby installation missing psych, suggests reinstall of libyaml and ruby, and still have image not found? RailsTutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, psych, libyaml

When using this command in the middle of my RailsTutorial ( on my laptop setup) :

```
rvm use 2.0.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default
```

I receive the following errors:

```
laptop:rubygems-1.8.25 USER_NAME$ rvm use 2.0.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default
Using /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451 with gemset railstutorial_rails_4_0
/Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/psych.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/psych.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/psych.bundle
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:600:in `load_yaml'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:314:in `load_file'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /Users/USER_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I've reinstalled libyaml, and reinstalled ruby, and it all returns back to these errors. No matter what I do, I always end up back at this list of errors.

Comment: What does this `rvm use 2.0.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default` should do?